# Laravel - Commit dynamically created collection to database for a given model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a collection in Laravel using:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection; // As per Mihir Bhende's answer, make sure we're using the correct Eloquent `Collection`

$collection = new Collection;
```

Then I proceeded to push multiple items (all of the same model type) into that collection:

```
$item = $items->first(function($item) {
    return $item->field == "value";
});

$collection->push($item);
```

And finally, I'm attempting to update all of the records that are now in `$collection` by using `$collection->update()` or `$collection->save()` but I'm receiving the follow error:

> "Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::update does not exist."

But since I'm using `new Collection` (and I've also tried `collect()`), and I'm calling `update()` non-statically, I was not expecting this error.

**How can I update my database records in `$collection` all at once?** Alternatively, is there a way to "queue" up changes on multiple different child objects that will not sacrifice performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use transactions to "queue" updates to the models and ensure atomic updates.

```
DB::transaction (function () use ($collection) {
    $collection->each(function ($item) {
        $item->save();
    });
});
```

Of course, the best way would to do your logic within the transaction Closure, so you don't need to loop them multiple times:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $items->each(function ($item) {
        $item->field = "value";
        $item->save();
    });
});
```

That way you don't need to loop over the collection multiple times.

See the Laravel documentation on transactions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#database-transactions

Answer (score 1):

When  you use collect([]), it created `Illuminate\Support\Collection` where as the eloquent models where we can use database update functions is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`

You can use Model::hydrate($array) to convert an array to eloquent collection.

But in your case if you are trying to save multiple records, see `Model::create()` or `Model::update()`. Se [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize there were two separate `Collection` classes. I've updated my code to use the Eloquent `Collection` now, but I'm now receiving effectively the same error: `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist.` Instead of setting `$collection = new Collection;`, my updated code now runs `$collection = Model::hydrate($array_of_items);` and then directly after that `$collection->update();`, so I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error.

Comment: Well I couldn't get past this error so I used `DB::transaction` from John Eriksson's answer.